# Black screen on Ionic Tabs

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a strange bug on my Ionic app. Trying to implement a tab page but when I load navigate to the page that supposed to have the tabs, I receive a black screen instead.

transportation-main.html

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]='transportationDetailsTab'></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]='transportationBidsTab'></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

transportation-main.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { TransportationDetailsPage, TransportationBidsPage } from '../pages';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-transportation-main',
  templateUrl: 'transportation-main.html',
})
export class TransportationMainPage {

  transportation: any;
  transportationDetailsTab: TransportationDetailsPage;
  transportationBidsTab: TransportationBidsPage;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) 
  {
    this.transportation = this.navParams.data;
  }

}
```

I don't have any console error and all 3 pages (TransportationMainPage, TransportationDetailsPage, TransportationBidsPage) are imported on modules.ts

I found on Google a few similar questions, but none of them had any solution.

And here is how I navigate to the tabs page from another component:

```
  onClick($event, item) {
    this.navCtrl.push(TransportationMainPage, item);
  }
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11015 Comment here says "updating manually ionic-angular to 3.5.3 solved the problem"

Comment: @JGFMK I have ionic-angular 3.6.0.. Should I downgrade?

Comment: I would ask on that thread perhaps. You've got nothing odd in the CSS/SASS have you?

Comment: I use a purchased ionic template but this page supposed to be from scratch. Nothing from the template is used... And checking the dev console didn't raise any CSS issue

Comment: If you look at the computed styles in Chrome and filter on color say, does unchecking some of the styles suddenly make content re-appear.. Specifically with black you'd be looking for RGB of 0 0 0 too - unless it was some 'off-black' colour. See what that yields. Maybe post a screenshot of that with the question.

Comment: Good idea about the computed styles, but I couldn't find something there too :(

Comment: LOL - was thinking chrome console screenshot from ionic serve. But that does clarify what's happening..

Comment: I've had a similar issue myself now when using Tabs in Ionic.

Comment: I've still not got the pages displaying the icons in the tabs.. But I got past the black screen....

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe u need to import your TransportationMainPage on your tabspage `import {TransportationMainPage} from './../TransportationMainPage';` and for your navigation try to type `(click)='this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage)`if you use ionic 2 or `ng-click='this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage)'` if you use ionic 1 maybe

Answer (score 0):

This may be only half the solution. Because I've not managed to get the icons to appear for the tabs...
But in your app.html - or whatever file you use in the app folder to render the html template... 
Wrap all the content in a `<ion-split-pane>`.
Also in the `<ion-nav>` use `main name="app"`.
That got rid of the black screen for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ah man, after searching for around an hour, I decided to generate a template of the `tabs` option via `ionic start`. I went through all my routes, thinking that the problem might be there.

Turns out, I forgot to import the `IonicModule` in my component hosting the tabs:

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        IonicModule,    // <-- This guy right here.
        CommonModule,
        ClientRoutes,
        ClientHomePageModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        ClientPage
    ]
})
export class ClientModule { }
```

After I put that in, all the content was displayed correctly, linking up to the tabs/components set up in the routing.